# In what sense is the equation of motion of a damped oscillator not time-symmetric?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Consider the equation of motion of a damped oscillator

$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + \gamma \frac{dx}{dt} + \omega_0^2 x = 0 \,. $$

Why does the equation of motion not satisfy time-symmetry? Is it related to drag term?

I am new to this area..so can you recommend related articles?

Comment: This equation is used in many domains, so you need to be more precise about the article recommendations, and also about the level of difficulty that you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. I've made several edits on this question. 1) I improved the title. Please see our [FAQ on question titles](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6413). 2) I used [mathjax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to replace the image of the equation. Please do not post images of equations here, and instead use mathjax. 3) I removed the Hamiltonian and Lagrangian tags because nothing in the question mentions Hamiltonian or Lagrangian methods.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is the drag term: it is easy to see that $y(t) = x(-t)$ satisfies equation
$$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} -\gamma\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + \omega_0^2y(t)=0.$$